# How could I possibly pass function to render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:
And I want to past the `template` that is inside of `init()` to `<TextForm props={template} />` as a `Modal`. Is it possible? How could I make it render?

I'm new in Class based, hopefully, someone can recode this to functional component..

```
  const getTooltip = (prop) => {
    switch (prop.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'img':
        return ImageForm;
      case 'bg-img':
        return ImageCSSForm;
      case 'video':
        return VideoForm;
      case 'empty':
        return EmptyForm;
      default:
        return TextForm;
    }
  };

  const findNearestChild = ($elm) => {
    if (
      $elm.prop('nodeName').toLowerCase() === 'img' ||
      $elm.prop('nodeName').toLowerCase() === 'video'
    ) {
      return $elm;
    }
    if ($elm.text().trim()) {
      return $elm;
    }
    for (var child of $elm.children()) {
      let tmp = findNearestChild($(child));
      if (tmp) {
        return tmp;
      }
    }
  };

  class ElementEditor {
    constructor($element) {
      this.$element = findNearestChild($element);
      const elementBG = `${this.$element[0].className}`;
      const bgImg = elementBG.includes('bg-img') && 'bg-img';

      if (!this.$element) {
        this.type = 'empty';
        this.$element = $element;
      } else if (bgImg === 'bg-img') {
        this.type = bgImg;
      } else {
        this.type = this.$element.prop('nodeName');
      }
    }

    init() {
      //todo: if no innerText show uneditable option
      let template = getTooltip(this.type);

      alert(template)

      $(window).on('keyup', this._onKeyUp.bind(this));
    }

    _onKeyUp(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        this.close();
      }
    }

    _removeListeners() {
      $(window).off('keyup', this._onKeyUp.bind(this));
    }

    close() {
      this._removeListeners();
    }

    static isInsideForm($element) {
      return $element.parents('.content').length;
    }
  }

  window.ElementEditor = ElementEditor;
```

Comment: What is `TextForm`?  This code is a bit strange for React.  We don't usually deal with intrinsic properties of DOM Nodes, since React is its own system for generating the DOM.

Comment: The `TextForm` is `Modal` from `reactstrap`

Comment: The initial code was pure js, and I was about to implement it in React

Comment: Look up the “render props” pattern.  Passing a component as a prop is totally okay!